# Merging index contents of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a string that I want to modify from. Hence I use the .split() function but there are times where my source will automatically add a space after a punctuation which I need to remove. I know how to isolate the punctuation (a comma in this instance) but not sure how to modify the list. What would be the best way of doing this?

```
    email_subject = "A B C D E F G H, I J"

    email_subject_contents_list = email_subject.split()

    for word in range(len(email_subject_contents_list)):

        print email_subject_contents_list[word]
        if email_subject_contents_list[word][-1] == ",":
            print("here it is at index %s" %(word))

    print email_subject_contents_list
```

Currently:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H,
here it is at index 7
I
J
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H,', 'I', 'J']
```

Ideally I want email_subject_contents_list to print out as

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H,I', 'J']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace` to replace `", "` to `","` and then use `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
email_subject = "A B C D E F G H, I J"
print( email_subject.replace(", ", ",").split() )
```

**Output:**

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H,I', 'J']
```